# MVC multiple db connection and appsettings

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I wonder if anybody know a solution to achieve this. 
Basically, I need to build a website like -

1) www.domain1.com/subApp1 goes to one database and one appsettings.
2) www.domain1.com/subApp2 goes to one database and one appsettings.

In Webform application -  I point the main domain (www.domain1.com) to a folder (landing) with a web.config which contains

```
    <location path="subApp1">
    <connectionStrings>
      <clear/>
      <add name="SchemaConnection" connectionString="data source=dev;initial catalog=Schema;user id=sa;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="brandName" value="subApp1"/>
      <add key="ImageLocation" value="~/uploaded/subApp1/"/>
    </appSettings>

  </location>
  <location path="subApp2">
    <connectionStrings>
      <clear/>
      <add name="SchemaConnection" connectionString="data source=dev;initial catalog=Schema2;user id=sa;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="brandName" value="subApp2"/>
      <add key="ImageLocation" value="~/uploaded/subApp2/"/>
    </appSettings>
  </location>
```

That works fine.  But in MVC, It ain't working. I hope there is a way to do in MVC to achieve this. Please advice if anyone know.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC runs on top of ASP.NET. So this should work exactly the same.

Comment: Well then I guess you did something wrong with your setup. And by the way by saying `it did not work` instead of explaining what exactly is the actual outcome you are not helping yourself very much to move this question any further than its current state - unanswered.

Comment: Sorry, I created asp.net webform application which pointed by www.domain1.com.  And I put  location path web.config things into that web application's web.config.   Then a mvc project points to subapp1 and same mvc project points to subapp2.  In main webconfig, location path="subapp1" and location path="subapp2" placed.